# Данные Child в Parent undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Пытаюсь извлечь данные из компонента `ColorChild` при помощи функции `setNewColor` которую передаю в `props`

```
class Color extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            currentColor: null
        }

        this.setNewColor = this.setNewColor.bind(this, true)
    }



    renderColors(color, index) {
        return (
            //ПЕРЕДАЮ ФУНКЦИЮ setNewColor В КОМПОНЕНТ ColorChild
            <ColorChild key={index} color={color} setNewColor={this.setNewColor} />
        )
    }

    setNewColor(color){
        console.log('setNewColor', color.name);
    }


    render() {
        const {color} = this.props
        return (
            <div className="product-item__block">
                <span className="product-item__title">Color</span>
                <div className="product-set">
                    {color.map((color, index) => this.renderColors(color, index))}
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

```
class ColorChild extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.sendColor = this.sendColor.bind(this)

    }

    sendColor(color){
        //ПЕРЕДАЮ ДАННЫЕ В РОДИТЕЛЯ
        this.props.setNewColor(color)
    }


    render() {
        const {color} = this.props
        return (

            <span onClick={() => this.sendColor(color)}
                  style={{backgroundColor : color.color}}
                  className={`product-set__item color ${(color.active ? 'active': '')}`}/>


        );
    }
}
```

В компоненте `ColorChild` использую функцию, она выполняется, но входной параметр undefined.

P.S делаю по аналогии http://jsbin.com/tipixiy/edit?js,output

Comment: что из себя представляет передаваемый `color`? Мб вы хотели вывести `color.color`?

Comment: @exvayn `color` это объект, но я думаю не суть что это. Он не передаётся

Comment: `setNewColor undefined` - это console.log?

Comment: @exvayn да, это console.log в родителе

Comment: Просто если бы объект `color` не пришел в родителя, то должна была вылезти ошибка на подобии - `вызов name у undefined`. В вашем случае выводится undefined в лог. Значит объект есть, а ключа `name` нет.

Comment: попробовал отправить просто `color`
Вывело:
`setNewColor true`

Comment: Я понял! проблема в `this.setNewColor = this.setNewColor.bind(this, true)`. Надо `this.setNewColor = this.setNewColor.bind(this)`. `true` - задается как первый параметр по умолчанию. А передаваемый `color` приходит 2-ым.

Comment: @exvayn дружище, ты меня спас, спасибо! Хотя я, вроде бы менял это значение, видимо что-то не правильно делал. Еще раз спасибо

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста!